# Javascript alert when new row is added to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

I need to give a javascript alert to users browser when a new record is added to database.  So far i have done this:

**PHP chatalert.php**

```
require("../system/config.php");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $rows;
```

**Javascript: test.php**

```
<?php 
define('BASEPATH', true);
require("../system/config.php");
?>
<script>

var old_count = 0;

setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "chatalert.php",
        success : function(data){
            if (data > old_count) {
                alert('new record on i_case');
                old_count = data;
            }
        }
    });
},1000);

</script>
```

But I always recive an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". So I will need some advice on this.

Mairo

Comment: have you tried jQuery then the $?

Comment: I have solved this problem by using a 2-step approach: 1) enter data to database   2) send chat message using socket.io (websockets) that fires off javascript on the client browser.

Comment: You're not including jQuery, but even so: you don't need JS for a task as simple as this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you included jquery? if not try adding this in your head tags

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

also make sure to parse the string to integer/Float for accurate result. The data returned by php can also be in string format:

```
var old_count = 0;
setInterval(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "chatalert.php",
        success : function(data){
            if (parseFloat(data) > old_count) {
                alert('new record on i_case');
                old_count = data;
            }
        }
    });
},1000);
```